# Jquery Modal position

Tags: jquery

Anyone can help me to find out what I am doing wrong. Why the pop up modal is not in center position ? I tried to manually set the position by using

position: { my: "center", at: "center"},

or position: { my: "center", at: "center",of: window },

Nothing seems working :(.

Reff:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Code:

```
 $("#btnPopup").click(function () {
            $("#buttonDialog").dialog({
                title: "Add a Manufacturer",
                modal: true,                
                buttons: {
                    "Add": addUser,
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: If not the centre, where does the popup seem to be aligned, can you provide a jsfiddle! replication of the problem? Doing so would help solve your problem a lot faster.

Comment: jsfiddle is showing the dialog in the center of screen. But in visual studio the dialog is popping up in the top left of the screen :(

Comment: ok, this can only be solved by providing a live link, where one can investigate what the problem is.

Comment: Never mind. It was css in master page messing up the jquery dialog. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I actually get it solved. If anyone else get similar issue, make sure you looked at all your css in master page as css can messed up your jQuery.